# Error while assigning observer collection to list box

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, observablecollection

Im having list box and I want to add to it items and when I tried with the following code I got error

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**

the error is when I do item source = _userList ,

what am I doing wrong here?

```
public ObservableCollection<User> _UsersList = new ObservableCollection<User>();

public MainWindow()
{
    _UsersList.Add(new User {Name = "Mike"});
    _UsersList.Add(new User { Name = "Nick" });
    listbox1.ItemsSource = _UsersList;
    DataContext = this;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this .InitializeComponent method must be called before using any element defined in xaml

```
 public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();

    _UsersList.Add(new User {Name = "Mike"});
    _UsersList.Add(new User { Name = "Nick" });
    listbox1.ItemsSource = _UsersList;
    DataContext = this;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should access UI element only after `InitializeComponent` gets called.

> ***InitializeComponent()*** is actually a method call to the partial class of the control which is responsible for rendering UI elements
>   for your control. So, if you access it before that it will always be
>   null since those are not initialized yet.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    _UsersList.Add(new User {Name = "Mike"});
    _UsersList.Add(new User { Name = "Nick" });
    DataContext = this;
    InitializeComponent();

    listbox1.ItemsSource = _UsersList;
}
```